# I am not able to create table. I get 150 error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

While I tried to create a table I got error can't create table problem 150. I googled this problem and found this is related to a foreign key constraint. Below is the code that I used to create table. Also used sqlfiddle to check the problem.

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `catalog_category_flat_store_1`;


 /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
 /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;   


  CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_flat_store_1` (
  `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'entity_id',
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'parent_id',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'created_at',
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'updated_at',
  `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'path',
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'position',
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'level',
  `children_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT         'children_count',
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
  `is_active` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Active',
  `url_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'URL Key',
  `description` text COMMENT 'Description',
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Image',
  `meta_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Page Title',
  `meta_keywords` text COMMENT 'Meta Keywords',
  `meta_description` text COMMENT 'Meta Description',
  `display_mode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Display Mode',
  `landing_page` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'CMS Block',
  `is_anchor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Anchor',
  `all_children` text COMMENT 'All Children',
  `path_in_store` text COMMENT 'Path In Store',
  `children` text COMMENT 'Children',
  `url_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Url Path',
  `custom_design` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Custom Design',
  `custom_design_from` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Active From',
  `custom_design_to` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Active To',
  `page_layout` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Page Layout',
  `custom_layout_update` text COMMENT 'Custom Layout Update',
  `available_sort_by` text COMMENT 'Available Product Listing Sort By',
  `default_sort_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Default Product Listing Sort By',
  `include_in_menu` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Include in Navigation Menu',
  `custom_use_parent_settings` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Use Parent Category Settings',
  `custom_apply_to_products` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Apply To Products',
  `filter_price_range` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Layered Navigation Price Step',
  `thumbnail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Thumbnail Image',
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_PATH` (`path`),
  KEY `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_LEVEL` (`level`),
  CONSTRAINT              `FK_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN  KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON    UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_FLAT_STORE_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID`    FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity`   (`entity_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Category Flat    (Store 1)';
```

When I click on detail of error link : Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

[ Variables | Buffer Pool | InnoDB Status ]

Comment: one of more of your FK references are failing, but since you've provided no details about table structures or even the actual error message, we can't help you. check `show engine innodb status`. there's a "last foreign key error" section buried in the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating catalog_category_flat_store_1 before "core_store" and "catalog_category_entity". This is why you got error. So, at first, create the prerequisite tables and then try the script.

Comment: You mean first I need to create 1. catalog_category_flat_store_1 
2. core_store 3. catalog_category_entity. I'm right.

Comment: How can I do this  create the prerequisite tables?

Comment: Ya, you need at first create these tables: "core_store" and "catalog_category_entity". But  you  really don't  need these tables at your business logic, so just run following code:

Answer (score 0):

```
             CREATE TABLE `catalog_category_flat_store_1` (
             `entity_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'entity_id',
            `parent_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'parent_id',
            `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'created_at',
            `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'updated_at',
            `path` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'path',
            `position` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'position',
            `level` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'level',
            `children_count` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT         'children_count',
             `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
            `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Name',
            `is_active` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Active',
            `url_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'URL Key',
            `description` text COMMENT 'Description',
            `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Image',
            `meta_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Page Title',
            `meta_keywords` text COMMENT 'Meta Keywords',
            `meta_description` text COMMENT 'Meta Description',
            `display_mode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Display Mode',
            `landing_page` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'CMS Block',
            `is_anchor` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Anchor',
            `all_children` text COMMENT 'All Children',
            `path_in_store` text COMMENT 'Path In Store',
            `children` text COMMENT 'Children',
            `url_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Url Path',
            `custom_design` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Custom Design',
             `custom_design_from` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Active From',
             `custom_design_to` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Active To',
             `page_layout` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Page Layout',
             `custom_layout_update` text COMMENT 'Custom Layout Update',
            `available_sort_by` text COMMENT 'Available Product Listing Sort By',
            `default_sort_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Default Product Listing Sort By',
            `include_in_menu` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Include in Navigation Menu',
            `custom_use_parent_settings` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Use Parent Category Settings',
             `custom_apply_to_products` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Apply To Products',
            `filter_price_range` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Layered Navigation Price Step',
             `thumbnail` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Thumbnail Image',
             PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
             KEY `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
             KEY `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_PATH` (`path`),
                KEY `IDX_CATALOG_CATEGORY_FLAT_STORE_1_LEVEL` (`level`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Catalog Category Flat    (Store 1)';
```

Comment: May I know the explanation?

Comment: I simply removed the foreign keys constraints from the table definition. As you said you actually don't know what r those tables. This is why I guessed you probably don't need them.